# How to apply pagestyle{empty} if section start on top of page

Tags: sectioning, titles, titlesec, page

How can I apply another pagestyle, if on top start new section `\section` and contain no text before.

Example

[image: Not change pagestyle]

Before start section on page are contained text. NOT change pagestyle

[[image: Change pagestyle to empty2]

Section start on top of page. Needed change pagestyle. So that there is no page number.

```
\documentclass[draft, twoside, 12pt, openright]{extreport}
\usepackage[a5paper, outer=20mm,inner=10mm,top=25mm,bottom=15mm,footskip=1.5em,headsep=4pt,headheight=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}    %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepackage{metalogo}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\usepackage{verse}
%\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

%\usepackage[all]{background}

\def\sectiontitlename{Розділ}
\def\parttitlename{Частина}

% -------------- Настраваем шрифты -----------------------------
\setmainfont[ItalicFont={Fregat Italic}]{Theano Old Style}
\setsansfont {Fregat}             % Sans font

\newfontfamily{\tobyfnt}{Tobi Dirt Black Rough}
\newfontfamily{\toprule}{adrops}
\newfontfamily{\avdirafnt}{Piron TW}
% --------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand\YUGE{\fontsize{48}{80}\selectfont} 

\newcommand*{\bibqufont}[1]{\bibquf\scriptsize{#1}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\bqseries}{\fontseries{ms}\selectfont}


% ---------------------------------------------------------------
%                  Modification TOP rule
% ---------------------------------------------------------------

\renewcommand\headrule{%
  \vspace{-1em}
  \hrulefill {\toprule\raisebox{-0.8pt}{C}\hrulefill}
}

% ------------------ END top rule dofication ---------------------


\fancypagestyle{headings}{%
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{} % except the center
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand\headrule{}
}

\let\fntshape\itshape
%\renewcommand{\itshape}{\sf\fntshape}


% --------------- Формат для оглавлений ------------------------
\titleformat{\part}
{\centering}
{\tobyfnt\YUGE\partname \space \thepart}
{1em}
{\thispagestyle{empty}}


\titleformat{\section}
{\avdirafnt\large\bfseries\centering}
{\sectiontitlename\space\thesection}
{-1.2em}
{}
[]

\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*1}

%\let\nonumberclearpage\clearpage
%\renewcommand{\clearpage}{\thispagestyle{empty}\nonumberclearpage}


% ---------------- Счетчики ------------------------
\newcounter{qenum}
\newcounter{q1}
\newlength{\mdffrw}

\newcommand{\qa}{\addtocounter{q1}{1}\arabic{q1})\ }

% ---------------- Основная информация книги ----------------------



% ================ Настройка некоторых параметров =================|
%\sloppy %----------------------------- Красивое формирование строк|
\tolerance=600
\parindent=2pc %-------------------------------Отступ первой строки|
\setlength{\columnsep}{14pt} %------------Растояние между колонками|
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.05pt} %----------Линия между колонками|
% -----------------------------------------------------------------|
%\tolerance=600
%\emergencystretch=2pt
\hfuzz=0.9pt
\doublehyphendemerits=9000000
% ---------------- Двухколоночное формирование текста -------------
%\twocolumn
\clubpenalty=10000
\widowpenalty=10000
\raggedbottom
\hyphenpenalty=800
\righthyphenmin=2

%\linespread{0.93}

\ULdepth = 0.2em




\newcommand{\versefont}{\itshape} % put here whatever font commands you want
\let\myoldverse\verse % now we store the original {verse}
\def\verse{\versefont\myoldverse}

\def\fs{\kern 0.2em}

%==================================================================
%                                                                 |
%                   BEGIN OF DOCUMENT                             |
%                                                                 |
%==================================================================

\makeatletter
\let\booktitle\@title
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}%clear all
\fancyhead{}%clear all
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\sffamily\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sffamily\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}

\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{
\vspace*{3pc}
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\parttitlename\space \thepart}{}
}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{\chaptertitlename\space \thesection}{}
}

\makeatletter

\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{}
\newpage
\fi\fi}
\makeatother

\counterwithin*{section}{part}

\begin{document}
\author{Ігор Юхименко}
\title{Краплини дощу}
\newcommand{\speek}{—\enspace}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
% \makeatletter
%  \@setfontsize\normalsize{13}{14.4}%
% \makeatother

%\setstretch{1.15}
% ================ Main content of book ========================


\input{Part1.tex}
%
\input{Part2.tex}
  
%   \part{}
%   \input{Part4.tex}
%
% =================================================================

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please let us know what document class you are using, and (best of all) provide a small compilable example that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.  That will give potential helpers something concrete to experiment with, rather than having to guess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I added information